# Scala function call with unknown default parameter

Tags: function, scala, default-value

Let's say I have a uncompilable (yes, I know it can't be compilled cuz of func()) code

```
 def withCondition(func: (Nothing) => Int): Unit = 
     if (someExtConditionIsTrue) func()
```

But the function I want to use with this wrapper looks like

```
def func(a: Int = 5) = a * 2
```

Is there any way I can call functions like this one inside the wrapper with it's own **default** parameter while I do not know what exactly that function was and what was it's default parameter value?

P.S.: I found the workaround via making `a` an Option or to check wherever it's null but the question still remain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a legit function and it properly uses default parameter:

```
def func(a: Int = 5) = a * 2
```

The type of this function is: `Int => Int`.

This code does not compile:

```
def withCondition(func: (Nothing) => Any): Unit = 
  if (someExtConditionIsTrue) func()
```

because your `func` is expected to be passed something of type `Nothing`. Perhaps what you meant is to have a function that takes no args:

```
def withCondition(func: => Int): Unit =
  if (someExtConditionIsTrue) func()
```

Or you can "push" default parameter to the wrapper function:

```
def withCondition(func: Int => Int, a: Int = 5): Unit =
  if (someExtConditionIsTrue) func(a)

// call it:
withCondition(func)
```

You can try implicit parameters instead of default ones like this:

```
implicit val defaultArg = 5
```

and then either:

```
def withCondition(func: Int => Int)(implicit a: Int): Unit = func(a)
```

or pass directly to `func`:

```
def func(implicit a: Int) = a * 2
```

**EDIT**

To call a function that has default arg you can use:

```
scala> def withCondition(func: => Int): Unit = println(func)
withCondition: (func: => Int)Unit

scala> def func(a: Int = 5) = a * 2
func: (a: Int)Int

scala> withCondition(func())
10

// or

scala> withCondition(func(3))
6
```

If you use this form: `def withCondition(func: => Int)` then it means that it takes a function that returns an Int and takes no args. In this case you have to provide that value for the function before you pass it to the wrapper function because wrapper function can't pass any args to a function that does not take args. In your case you achieve that either by using default arg or by explicitly passing an arg to `func` like in the examples above.

Comment: Hence the saying, "you can't get some Int from Nothing".

Comment: Aleksey, how to call the fuction with it's own default while you do not know what this function exactly is. That's why the wrapper is declared so unspecified.

Comment: So now I think I pretty much described all kinds of options. The only thing I would change is to work out correct type of `func` arg. If it ignores return value (Unit) then it's better to declare it that way ;). But that's a separate concern/question.